# Как настроить уведомления в Outlook

Tags: windows, outlook

Когда письма приходят напрямую в папку "Входящие" то выскакивает виндовское уведомление о новом письме. Я создал правило, что какие-то письма направлять в другую папку, и когда туда падают письма, уведомления не приходят. Как можно сделать чтобы по ним также уведомления приходили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для включения уведомлений правил, необходимо в настройках каждого правила добавить действие
`вывести оповещение на рабочем столе`